# Export gridPanel to excel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, export, ext.net, gridpanel

I want to export my gridPanel to excel. I am using ext.net(Version 1.6) and vb.net code behind and i don't want to use any java script function.
Please Take a look at this function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var saveData = function () {
GridData.setValue(Ext.encode(GrdAppointment.getRowsValues({ selectedOnly: false })));};
</script>
```

Is it possible to use an equivalent of this function from vb?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent. Please clarify why do you not want to use JavaScript for that operation?

Comment: Hello Daniil,
I do not want to use JavaScript because i can't use listeners to call JavaScript function (am already using DirectEvent for my button).
So what i put this java script function in aspx header! 
But i don't know how to call this function from vb.net.

Comment: I tried this:
`code`System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "Script", "saveData();", True) `code`
but it's not working

Comment: To call a JavaScript function from server side you can use X.Js.Call("saveData").